# Index Position in a 2D list to get a sub return value from same list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically atm i've made two different lists, and their places are respective of each other.
User inputs an item name. The program searches for its index in the pre-defined list and then gives its respective value from the second list.

What i want is the list on the first comment (2d list) to work. Is it possible that using that list, a user inputs : 'Bread'.

The program gets its index and then returns the value 5.
Basically indexing in 2d list.I've searched a lot but to no avail.

If you could provide a code or atleast guide me the right way.

Thanks.

```
#super_market_prices=[['Bread',5],['Loaf',100],['Meat_Chicken',2.4],['Meat_Cow',450]]
'''
Program listing Super Market Prices
Search by name and get the price
'''
super_market_items=['Bread','Loaf','Meat_Chicken','Meat_Cow']
super_market_prices=[5,4,20,40]

item=str(input('Enter item name: '))
Final_item=item.capitalize()                    #Even if the user inputs lower_case
                                                #the program Capitalizes first letter
try:
    Place=super_market_items.index(Final_item)
    print(super_market_prices[Place])
except ValueError:
    print('Item not in list.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want a 2D list, you want a dictionary, and luckily, it's super simple to go from a 2D list (where each sublist has only two elements) to a dictionary:

```
prices = [['Bread',5],['Loaf',100],['Meat_Chicken',2.4],['Meat_Cow',450]]
d = dict(prices)
# {'Bread': 5, 'Loaf': 100, 'Meat_Chicken': 2.4, 'Meat_Cow': 450}
```

Now all you have to do is query the dictionary (O(1) lookup):

```
>>> d['Bread']
5
```

If you want to enable error checking:

```
>>> d.get('Bread', 'Item not found')
5
>>> d.get('Toast', 'Item not found')
'Item not found'
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. To basically do it without getting two lists.

Comment: and i was also just checking that error status...and you clarified it yourself :).

Comment: Happy to help.  When you have dependent variables like this, it's much easier (and much more efficient) to use a dictionary as a data structure as opposed to a list.  Otherwise you're doing O(n) lookup every time you need to access something.

Comment: Yep, I added in the error checking to show how to handle a key not existing in the dictionary.  I would highly recommend the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) if you're interested in learning more.

Comment: Oh that'll help a lot. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It seems to fail if we use `Final_item=item.capitalize()`. Try inputting 'Meat_Chicken' and it will become 'Meat_chicken' and `d[Final_item]` eventually result in an error.

Comment: I would use `item.title()` instead, as it will capitalize each word, not just the first :)

Comment: Oh! That i didn't had in mind really. Thanks a lot for going through it so thoroughly. I really wouldn't have gone for that one. THANKSSSS :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily go from your "2d-list" from those two separate sequences by using `zip`

```
super_market_prices=[['Bread',5],['Loaf',100],['Meat_Chicken',2.4],['Meat_Cow',450]]

l1, l2 = zip(*super_market_prices)

>>> print(l1)
('Bread', 'Loaf', 'Meat_Chicken', 'Meat_Cow')
>>> print(l2)
(5, 100, 2.4, 450)
```

and just keep your code as is.

Comment: Thanks.But i wanted it basically to be without creating 2 separate lists

Comment: @Cizhu ah I see :) Thought you wanted a quick fix to the code

Comment: Sorry if the question came across as such. My bad. Well i didn't knew about the zip command before...but now i know that. So thanks still :) .

Answer (score 1):

This is another work around to your problem. P.S: I used @user3483203's suggestion to use `item.title()` instead of `item.capitalize()` as the latter was resulting in error for the string with an underscore. Here I am making use of the fact that each item is succeeded by its price. Hence `index+1`

```
super_market_prices=np.array([['Bread',5],['Loaf',100],['Meat_Chicken',2.4],['Meat_Cow',450]]).ravel()

item=str(input('Enter item name: '))
Final_item=item.title()      

try:
    index = np.where(super_market_prices == Final_item)[0] 
    print (float(super_market_prices[index+1][0]))
except ValueError:
    print('Item not in list.')
```

Comment: Oh . This is actually quite the trick. Thanks...really. This helps a lot, also in my understanding of it. Thankyou :)